# blinding(crypthology) in java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I have a message like 'example'.

Firstly i want to blind this message,later encode,unblind, and finally decode this message.

Im new to this subject.How can i do these things in java .Is there a library of java about this subject.Can you give me links about this.I

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what 'blinding' is, but a reasonable starting point for Java crypto is [bouncy castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/), or the java.com tutorial on JCE.

Comment: Indeed, bouncycastle has an implementation of RSA blinding for the OP's perusal.

Answer (score 0):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#SimpleEncrEx looks like a reasonable starting example for how to do some basic (symmetric) encryption in Java.